# Run testcase on Amazon Device Farm from local

Tags: java, appium, aws-device-farm

I am using Amazon Device Farm for execution of test cases via automation. 
So i wanted to know that if it is possible to execute the testcases on Amazon Device Farm from my local machine using some URL to connect to ADF like perfecto or mobile labs.

Thank you all in advance !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Device Farm does have the feature called Direct Device Access (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/devicefarm/latest/developerguide/direct-device-access.html).

To use this feature, you need to have a private device in Device Farm. (https://aws.amazon.com/device-farm/pricing/#privateDevices)